# Suddenly Session datas destroyed when redirect page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cpanel

I have to work in multiple subdomains. Suddenly I can't access my all subdomains. Because when the page redirects session data was lost. This issue happens my all subdomains
   But I didn't change anything from my server. Anyone, please help me why this issue suddenly happened and how to fix this issue
   My domain was hosted in cpanel.
   But My code working perfectly in localhost

Comment: Perhaps you set the session cookie to only be valid for the top-level domain?

Comment: How to check session  cookie was only top level domain or not?  but all domains are working perfect since yesterday.but suddenly this issue was happen. suppose i set session cookie only top level domain then how all domains worked well since yesterday.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't have worked yesterday if that was the issue.

Comment: I can't understand your answer.please explain briefly

Comment: I was agreeing with what you said.

Comment: which session driver do you use? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers. If you use files driver, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554425/2275490

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: This issue gets fixed in CI v3.1.1. Please upgrade to >= 3.1.1 to totally get rid of this issue.**

@prakasht - I had been facing a similar problem and found this while looking up for a fix. For me it happened while trying to upgrade CI v2.2.6 --> v3.0.3

Suddenly my sessions stopped working. I added some logs to debug the scenario in the sessions file-based driver `system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php`

Having centralized sessions in my earlier as well as current place of work, I found that somehow the session was re-created for the every request based on the logs I added.

As a lazy person, I tried to google my way through it when I saw your [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54586229/6670698).

This was till now the closest I had seen someone get to solving this issue with Ci as everyone else just adds hacks. I tried to debug the code in the file `system/libraries/Session/Session.php` on my own and found that the sanitization `preg_match()` never matches.

In the regex trying to check the cookie value tried to match with

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            && (
                ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
                OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            )
        )
```

I tried to match my cookie value with the regex `^[0-9a-f]{40}$` and found that it failed. So, going by the definition in the file `application/config/config.php`, I changed the regex to  `^[0-9a-z_-]{1,40}$` which basically means that the regex can match any cookie value between lengths 1 - 40 comprising of characters in any one or a mix of set `0-9, a-z, _ , -`.

*Code with fixed regex*

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            && (
                ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
                OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-z_-]{1,40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            )
        )
```

This fixed it for me. Hope it does the same for you.

P.S.: I have also replaced all instances of

`$this->session->all_userdata()` with `$this->session->userdata()`

and

`$this->session->set_userdata($key, $value)` with `$this->session->key = $value`

inside my codebase as per [CI 2.2.x -> 3.x upgrade documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html) and [Session library documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

**UPDATE: This issue gets fixed in CI v3.1.1. Please upgrade to >= 3.1.1 to totally get rid of this issue.**

Answer (score 0):

I Changed small modification session.php file

before change code:

```
// Sanitize the cookie, because apparently PHP doesn't do that for userspace handlers
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            && (
                ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
                OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            )
        )
        {
            unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);
        }
```

AFTER:

i changed 32 instead of 40

```
// Sanitize the cookie, because apparently PHP doesn't do that for userspace handlers
        if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            && (
                ! is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
                OR ! preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{32}$/', $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']])
            )
        )
        {
            unset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]);
        }
```

In this case session data loads based on cookie id. But The cookie id was max 32.But previous code define 40.when cookie id was between 33 and 40.the session data was loss

But My Doubt is how the previous code Worked well since 2 days before in live ?.  AT the same time previous code still working in my localhost ?